# SQL Connection only works with integrated security

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to establish a connection to a server+catalog by providing some credentials.

The code that I have is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string connectionString;
             SqlConnection cnn;
             connectionString = @"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DEMO;User ID=reportsuser;Password=reportsuser";

             cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
             cnn.Open();

             MessageBox.Show("Connection Open!");
             cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I click the button I obtain an error message telling me that

> Login failed for user 'reportsuser'

Entered credentials are correct, though.

However, if I use the `Integrated Security` on that user Windows session, I can access.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
  public Form1()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   string connetionString;
   SqlConnection cnn;
   connetionString = @"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DEMO;Integrated security = true;";
   cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
   cnn.Open();
   MessageBox.Show("Connection Open!");
   cnn.Close();
  }
 }
}
```

With this, I obtain the message *Connection Open!*
Why can I only access by using Integrated security from *reportsuser* and I cannot access by providing reportsuser credentials directly on the C# code?

Comment: Do you get the same login failure when manually connecting to the SQL instance with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Username/password passed in the connection string are specifically for using SQL logins, which are not enabled by default. They *do not* allow you to pass *windows* username/password, which is what it sounds to me like you're trying to do.

Comment: @gunr2171 No. I obtain no failures on SQL Server Management Studio with reportsuser credentials

Comment: SQL Login and Windows credentials are matching for this case, @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: It doesn't matter if they match. If you're using SQL Credentials, then the SQL user needs to be created and assigned to the server and database. SQL users and Windows users are entirely separate entities, even if the name is the same. Are you sure you in SSMS you can connect _with SQL credentials_ and query the database?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, I can connect and query the database using those credentials.

Comment: Check the logs and get the true authentication error, as the errors passed to the application layer are intentionally vague. If you don't understand said error then [edit] your question ans include the error.

Comment: Using SSMS what option are you using in login window (Window Credentials or SQL)?  Integrated Security is Windows Credentials.

Comment: Client-side login failure messages are intentionally vague. To determine what the real login problem is look in the SQL Server's `ERRORLOG` file for error 18456 messages and compare their `State` number against the values posted at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error). Likely the SQL Login's password is incorrect, or that SQL Login doesn't have a User mapping in the `DEMO` database.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I accessed the errorlog file as suggested and between all my failed attempts to access, there's one that I think explains it:
"Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only."